# Java convert from byte array to String to byte array again

Tags: java, arrays, spring, pdf, byte

I have a byte array that I need to convert to a String to send it in a POJO to another microservice. This microservice should convert it again into a byte array and finally into a pdf file.

My code:

Creation of Byte array and conversion into string

```
byte[] bytes = proIntegrationService.loadDownloadDocument(accountId, dcId);
        PDFDocument pdfDocument = new PDFDocument(dcId+".pdf", new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
        return pdfDocument;
```

Microservice retrieving String and converting into PDF file:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/offers/{offerId}/contract")
 @ApiOperation(value = "Download an offer contract")
 @ApiResponses(value = @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ""))

 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadOfferContract(
        @PathVariable Long offerId, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        JsonNode pdf = brokerageApplicationService.downloadOfferDocument(offerId, request);
        byte [] data =pdf.get("file").textValue().getBytes("UTF-8");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String filename = pdf.get("fileName").asText();
        headers.set("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\""+filename+"\"" );
        headers.set("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.setContentLength(data.length);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(data, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

        return response;


    }
```

The PDF output looks like this:

//Some lines

```
%PDF-1.4
%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
2 0 obj
<</Length 52/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xï¿½+ï¿½r
ï¿½26Sï¿½00Õ³ï¿½TIï¿½r
ï¿½
ï¿½*T0T0Bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Resources<</XObject<</Xf1 1 0 R>>/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.28 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 52/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xï¿½+ï¿½r
ï¿½26Sï¿½00Õ³ï¿½TIï¿½r
ï¿½
ï¿½*T0T0Bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

The result is -> content is "there" - so the PDF file has a size of 7MB round about - but everything is just white.

what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you just send the bytes encoded as base64 instead of  parsing it into a string and back?

Comment: I tried that before and did also not work - might be I did something wrong - how would your code look like? :)

Comment: Basically I'd use something like `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( bytes )` and `Base64.getDecoder().decode( your_parameter )`. If this doesn't work then try to debug your code, e.g. by reading the file and writing it back at several stages of your process to see where it goes wrong. Additionally you could write the encoded and sent strings to text files and compare those.

Comment: I tried again with Base64 encoding - does also not work

Comment: String and getBytes won't do. If the bytes are already the binary image of a PDF, one either would pass them on as PDF, or create the PDFDocument with a `new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)` as InputStream parameter. _This can be checked by the 4 first bytes ("%PDF", aka 37, 80, 68, 70)._

Comment: As stated, make sure your input file is correct and then try to debug your process, i.e. read the file and write several copies of it somewhere to see where it starts to go wrong. If you're already reading your file in a wrong way the end result won't change even if the rest of the code is correct.

Comment: When I was doing similar thing my process was adding an empty line at the end of the file. Try to do the binary compare the newly generated PDF with the original PDF just to visualize the difference. WinMerge can be helpful in this case.